# Other duplicates of 'What should main() return in C and C++'?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, duplicate-questions

The question [What should `main()` return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-c) is, I believe, the earliest one on SO to cover the topic.  It has a number of decent answers. As such, it should be considered the canonical question for the topic.

It also has a number of duplicates, including:

- [What are the valid signatures for C's `main()` function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108192/what-are-the-valid-signatures-for-cs-main-function/)
- [The return type of `main()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17715008/the-return-type-of-main-function/)
- [Difference between `void main()` and `int main()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636829/difference-between-void-main-and-int-main)

They're the ones I know of.  Do you know of any others?  If so, I'd like to:

1. Ensure that they are closed as duplicates of the canonical question, and
2. Add the link to the list on the canonical question's page.

Note that as I type, 'What are the valid signatures for C's `main()`' and 'Difference between `void main()` and `int main()`' are not closed as duplicates — please contribute close votes for them, too.

Comment: You don't need to post a question for meta to do this.  If you think the other questions are all duplicates vote to close them; that's all.  The close vote queue will help ensure you get adequate views by possible close voters.  There's really only a need for a meta post if there's a lot of argument/controversy over what to do.  There's also no need to link all of the duplicates on the canonical question.  If the other questions have really valuable content you can flag for merger, and they'll be seen in the "related" tab when viewing the post as well.

Comment: I don't know the 'other' duplicates — I'm expecting that there are other duplicates and hoping that people who know of them (because, for example, they contributed an answer to it) will list them and make sure they're closed.  I've done what I can for the questions I know about — I can't do anything for those I don't know about.  It isn't an easy search to make, unfortunately — the terms 'return', 'main', 'int', 'void' in the C and C++ tags are ubiquitous.

Comment: Where's the 'flag for merger' item?

Comment: There's no real reason to do this.  If you come across a duplicate naturally, vote to close.  If you suspect a question you come across has a duplicate, find it, and then vote to close.  There are better things for us to spend our time on then trying to search out all duplicates of this question.

Comment: There is no predefined flag reason for flagging for merging, just use the custom reason.

Comment: OK — then this question is not addressed to you, Servy, if you don't think that this needs addressing.  Thanks for the info on 'flagging for merger'; it explains why I've not seen it in my travels.

Comment: If you want to go and spend a bunch of time going to find duplicates, you can.  You're the one asking others to go do the work for you.

Comment: @Servy: My question is "Do you know of any others", not "Can you go and find any others".  There's a big difference.  What I'm asking is "if you happen to already know of such questions, or remember providing one or more answers to such questions, and if you are willing, then please provide the information".  It is not "Please go out and find any such duplicates" because I know that it is not easy to do that with the search tools because the search terms are ubiquitous.  However, we are simply going to have to agree to disagree on this.

Comment: @Servy really, let the close vote queue of 100k take care of closing? It's pretty clearly if you actually want to get something cleaned up, you need to go to chat or meta for it.

Comment: @djechlin That's not true at all.  Many thousands of questions get closed each day without the help of either of those.  And if everyone feels that way then all of meta/chat will become useless due to the flood of "please close this" questions.

Comment: @Servy very few people feel the desire to do a cleanup like in this post, but I would like to encourage it when they do, and existing mechanisms don't work well. If hundreds of users suddenly start this "topical" clean up and come to meta, then maybe SE will do something about the close queue.

Comment: @djechlin Lots of things have been and continue to be done with respect to the queue.  It has has quite a few feature requests added over the past year.  SE has been doing quite a lot about the queue.  Making meta unusable would only be counter productive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are now 7 direct duplicates and 4 closely related questions linked to the master question.

Comment: Don't forget to flag for merging if there are good answers on any of the dups