# Getting unexpected bonus for accepting self-answered answers on MSO

Tags: discussion, reputation, meta, self-answer

I had a number of questions on MSO without an answer. I added an answer to two of them and got awarded 2 points reputation.  The blog entry [Accept your own answers](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) says that won't happen.  So does the answer to [Do you get reputation for self-answered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116090/do-you-get-reputation-for-self-answered-questions)

Is it a bug or a change of policy?

(I can't test SO; I don't have questions there without answers over there.)

---

I goofed — it was too early in the morning.  Ignore this question.  Those who answered get their rep, though.

Comment: What questions did you accept? I only see you get points for answers posted by *others*.

Comment: Oh...brain death...caffeine-starvation.  Do not up-vote this question, please!

Comment: Up-voted due to admission of brain death ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You accepted 4 answers today; 2 were self-answers and gave you 0 points:

- [SO broke a working URL by mapping parentheses () to %28%29](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210027/so-broke-a-working-url-by-mapping-parentheses-to-2829/215017#215017)
- [Other duplicates of 'What should main() return in C and C++'?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196470/other-duplicates-of-what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c/215019#215019)

It was the *other* two answers that you *also* accepted that gave you +2 points each:

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202746/merge-tags-timestamp-and-timestamps/202751#202751 by Lance Roberts
- [Should the 'close as off-topic' menu provide a write-in option for the alternative site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175565/should-the-close-as-off-topic-menu-provide-a-write-in-option-for-the-alternati/175603#175603) by jonsca

You can easily see this on your reputation tab:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your reputation you got 2 rep for accepting the answer to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202746/merge-tags-timestamp-and-timestamps/202751#202751 and [Should the 'close as off-topic' menu provide a write-in option for the alternative site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175565/should-the-close-as-off-topic-menu-provide-a-write-in-option-for-the-alternati/175603#175603)

You didn't get it for accepting your own answer, which shows up as giving you 0 reputation:

[image]

Your cached reputation on the User Reputation Leagues, from yesterday, is 5,525, which implies that the reputation tab in your profile is correct.